# Отловить Tag с NDEF сообщением при помощи NFC

Tags: android-intent, android, nfc

Я записал NDEF сообщение на **Tag**, которое содержит **uri** для включения моего приложения (приложение наподобие **TagInfo**, которое считывает серийник и техлист). После включения приложения оно должно сразу считать **Tag** и выдать по нему инфу, но этого не происходит, т.к. не передаётся **intent**, который содержит этот **Tag**, поэтому необходимо ещё раз убрать **Tag** и поднести снова, а это не есть хорошо.

Проблема в том, может, я и ошибаюсь, но для меня это пока самое разумное объяснение, что есть внутренний **service** в **android**, который считывает метку, видит, что в нём есть **NDEF сообщение**, парсит его, и после того, как обнаружил имя пакета приложения и **TNF** байт, который отвечает за то, что необходим запуск этого приложения, он просто создаёт новый **intent**, который не содержит **Tag**, и просто запускает его, т.к. я считывал **Action** в **OnCreate()**, и он равен **Action.MAIN**, т.е. тоже самое, если бы я запустил приложение через иконку.

Пробовал уже **BroadcastReceiver**, но он не помог, и это было очевидно, т.к. **intent-ы** с **Action** равными **ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED**, **ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED** и **ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED** отлавливаются через **OnNewIntent()**, а он привязан к **Activity** и не будет вызван, т.к. нового **intent** не придёт, он уже был обработан сервисом андроида. Вот тут и есть вся проблема, ведь туда-сюда крутить телефоном не есть хорошая идея для пользователя.

На данный момент попробую запихнуть **OnNewIntent()** в мой **Service**, но думаю, что он не отловит вообще ничего, т.к. он отлавливает только в **Activity**. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема решается добавлением в файл манифеста фильтра намерений наподобие следующего:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
      <data android:scheme="Ваш_uri" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: К сожалению нет, проблема состояла в том, что решения для моей проблемы нету в принципе, т.к. Tag отлавливается единожды и передаётся только одному приложения, а т.к. в Tag был записан Uri на включение моего приложения, то данный Tag был обработан системным приложением и в последствии он не передаётся в моё приложение